# Alias if script matches variable, quotation issues

Tags: quotes, double-quotes, bash

I'm trying to write an `alias` for a common command to cancel a process, but I'm having issues with the single and double quotations.  This is my first attempt at Bash scripting and I'm a bit stumped.

```
lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '$1 == "Google" {print $2}'
```

This works as a stand-alone command and outputs the correct PID.

When I try formatting it as an alias though I'm having issues.  I know the command is stopping at the first single quote by the way this is structure but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
alias test='lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '$1=="Google" {print $2}''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no escape sequence for single quotes inside single quotes. You can't write `\'` like you might expect. So there are two options.

1. You can break out of single quotes, add an escaped single quote `\'`, and then go back in, like so:

   ```
   alias test='lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '\''$1 == "Google" {print $2}'\'
   ```
2. You can use double quotes. You then have to escape not just the double quotes inside the string but also the dollar signs.

   ```
   alias test="lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '\$1 == \"Google\" {print \$2}'"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your alias like this

```
alias test='lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '"'"'$1=="Google" {print $2}'"'"
```

The single quotes `'` must be escaped between double quotes `"`. To do so, the command has to be split into several parts to escape them differently. `lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '$1=="Google" {print $2}'` can be split on single quotes like this

1. `lsof -i tcp:80 | awk`
2. `'`
3. `$1=="Google" {print $2}`
4. `'`

Then quote with appropriate quotes

1. `'lsof -i tcp:80 | awk'`
2. `"'"`
3. `'$1=="Google" {print $2}'`
4. `"'"`

And merge every part together and you have your alias:

```
'lsof -i tcp:80 | awk'"'"'$1=="Google" {print $2}'"'"
```

Note that the first part does not contain any interpreted variable so it can be quoted with double quotes and merged with the second part. Thus the alias becomes

```
alias test="lsof -i tcp:80 | awk'"'$1=="Google" {print $2}'"'"
```

Comment: Thanks this works too, giving John the check as his was a tad more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every case where find yourself trying to define an alias, define a function instead.

```
testing () {
    lsof -i tcp:80 | awk '$1=="Google" {print $2}'
}
```